# Вопрос по пунктуации. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

«Я вот не понимаю понравился он мне или нет?» Запятая, двоеточие или простой пропуск между «понимаю» и «понравился»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны варианты: двоеточие или запятая. Но не пропуск, так как это два простых предложения в составе бессоюзного сложного.

*Я вот не понимаю [того], понравился он мне или нет?* || Лучше.
После двоеточия можно подставить "*а именно*" (проверка на целесообразность знака).
*Я вот не понимаю: [а именно] понравился он мне или нет?* || Хуже. Это перечисление. Оно удачно, если варианты самостоятельны, различны (см. первое предложение ответа). А здесь две стороны одной медали — да или нет.
Сравнить:
*Я вот не понимаю: нравится он мне или вызывает чувство отвращения?*

Answer (score 3):

Если это *вопрос* (в конце выбран вопросительный знак), риторический он или реальный, то между повествовательной частью (сообщение о недоумении) и вопросительной (раскрывающей содержание недоумения - какой вопрос возникает) нужно **двоеточие**.

Возможна и повествовательная трактовка всего предложения, с соответствующей интонацией и точкой в конце. В этом случае говорящий, не задаваясь вопросом, просто *сообщает*, что не знает (= не понимает), какая из называемых им альтернатив верна. Соответственно, нужна **запятая**.

Comment: Думаю, что и обратная пунктуация возможна. Но ваш вариант лучше.

Comment: Двоеточие - это знак, который в современных текстах используется не так часто, обычно в тех случаях, когда он действительное необходим, а это не тот случай. Предложение по структуре больше соответствует СПП, а там вопросительная интонация допускается. В этом случае интонационно и логически выделена вторая часть. Поэтому сочетание запятая и вопросительный знак вполне допустимы, и  это лучший вариант. Вариант с двоеточием может выглядеть так:Я вот что не понимаю: понравился он мне или нет? Здесь уже без двоеточия не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше или хуже? Так мне нравится, а так не нравится. Но о вкусах, как говорится, не спорят. Поэтому при обосновании парных вариантов письма надо находить и указывать на **семантические различия**, и тогда автор сам выберет, что ему лучше, а что хуже.

(1) **Я вот не понимАю: понравился он мне или нЕт**?

Классически вариант бессоюзного предложения. **Логическим ударением выделены обе части**, так как двоеточие обозначает предупредительную увеличенную паузу.

Но немного смущает лексика глагола *понимать* и вопрос в конце предложения. Кому задан вопрос? Более походящий вариант: *Я вот думаю: понравился он мне или нет*? Этот вопрос задан себе.

(2) **Я вот не понимаю (чего?), понравился он мне или нет?**

Упрощенное оформление бессоюзного предложение, которое в этом случае близко с сложноподчиненному предложению с пропущенной вопросительной частицей ЛИ в качестве союза: Я вот не понимаю, понравился (ли) он мне или нЕт?

Логическим ударением выделена **только вторая (вопросительная) часть.**

Второй вариант представляется более подходящим, но выбор за автором.